# Rotating screen, is calling activity's life-cycle more than one time

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a single Activity application which has **map fragment**.

When activity starts, following activity lifecycle will be called

```
onCreate
onStart
onResume
```

But when I rotate device, following lifecycle is going to be called!

```
onPause
onStop
onDestroy
onCreate
onCreate
onStart
onStart
onResume
onResume
```

When I rotate it again,

```
onPause
onPause
onStop
onStop
onDestroy
onDestroy
onCreate
onCreate
onCreate
onStart
onStart
onStart
onResume
onResume
onResume
```

My code is below

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        activityMapBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_maps)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        val mapFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        observeErrorResponse()

        Log.d("MainActivity","onCreate")
    }


override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mainViewModel.syncStart()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onStart")
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mainViewModel.syncStop()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onStop")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onPause")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onResume")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onDestroy")
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onRestart")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not familiar with kotlin but in java (which I use) I would check to see if a fragment was already added in fragment manager, if it has already been added, don't add another one, because when configuration state changes (screen rotation in your case), android destroys the activity and re-creates it. So your activity's lifecycle methods would be called again

Comment: this is not my question. Do you think because of fragment these life cycles are calling more than once?

Answer (score 0):

You have to "save"/"store" the data when this happens. Implement this before the `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outstate.<type in put in android studio and select the one you need in the dropdown options(such as putParceleable, putString, putInt etc.)>(<Create a const val variable in a separate kotlin file and put the name of the variable here(it will act as the key), android studio will automatically import it>, <here you need to put the variable that contains the data that is being removed/gone when you rotate the device>)
}
```

Then implement this after `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`:

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        <name of the variable you put in the outstate> = savedInstanceState.<type in get and select the one you need(it must be the same as the one in the put, ex. if you have put putString, provide getString here.)>(<name of the key you implemented in the outstate>)
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it help me in Activity lifecycle?

Comment: It helps you store any data that you may be losing when the user rotates the screen.